# Capybara not working in my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am using Capybara (used both 1.1.1 and 1.1.2) in a rails 3.1.0 application.  I am trying to get Capybara running for my integration testing using the chromedriver.  When I run the test suite ever test case fails with this error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to connect to chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:53468
```

When I do not use the chromedriver firefox will also not work.  The weird thing is that when I use capybara from `irb` (not the rails console) it works fine.  But, When I try to use it with my Rails application loaded the above error always happens.

I guess it has something to do with the dependencies I am loading since I am running Capybara fine in a different (Rails 2) project.

If it helps here is my gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.6'

gem 'pg'



gem 'json'
gem 'alchemist'
gem "rails-backbone"

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.1.0.rc"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0.rc"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :test, :development do
  gem 'jasmine'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 1.1"
end
```

My spec Helper looks like this:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
```

require 'capybara/rails'

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec
end
```

Thanks for any ideas.

PS. not sure if this is helpful but when I use `chromedriver-helper` gem I get this error instead:

```
no such file to load -- {"sessionId":"bcdf4c348c8f976cbe20f98120a456d0","status":0,"value":{"acceptSslCerts":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"browserName":"chrome","chrome.chromedriverVersion":"19.0.1068.0","chrome.nativeEvents":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"handlesAlerts":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"nativeEvents":true,"platform":"mac","rotatable":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"version":"18.0.1025.168","webStorageEnabled":false}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Require these files in spec_helper

```
  require 'capybara/rspec'
  require 'capybara/rails'
```

also check [this post](http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/02/capybara-and-selenium-with-rspec-and-rails-3/)

Comment: Thanks,  I have added them but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

We also had to set the javascript_driver to :chrome

i.e. features/support/chrome.rb:

```
# Use Chrome for Selenium (@javascript) browser-based tests in Capybara.
# Chromedriver, the Chromium project's selenium webdriver adapter, must
# be installed on the test server.  To ease the installation and use of
# chromedriver, the chromedriver-helper gem is specified in the Gemfile.
#
# Updating Chromedriver
# =====================
# If you'd like to force-upgrade to the latest version of chromedriver,
# run the script 'chromedriver-update' that comes packaged with this
# gem.
# This might be necessary on platforms on which Chrome auto-updates,
# which has been known to introduce incompatibilities with older versions
# of chromedriver.

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

# The chromedriver-helper docs don't list this as a requirement.
# We only know about it from other chrome driver docs.
Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```